# office outlook 2007 not receiving from a certain e-mail address

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2007

Somebody that I have regularly recieved e-mails from with outlook is now unable to send me e-mails. I know this because they CC another e-mail address I have and while I receive the e-mails to my gmail account they do not show up in outlook. Nothing has changed that I know of, and the e-mails are not being rejected and sent back to her computer. I have gone into my safe list and added her e-mail address and the domain name it comes from. Any ideas what I have inadvertaly done and how to fix it? Also they are not going to the junk folder.

Comment: What type of email account do you use? (POP, IMAP or Exchange)

Comment: it is a pop/SMTP account

Answer (score 1):

Check not only the "safe list" inside Outlook, but the white list from the email provider. For instance, if you're account is a GMAIL account, log into gmail and look for the Spam folder and see if the message went in there.

Often, if emails quietly dissappear and you aren't notified of it, they have been tagged as spam somewhere along the line. Think about different steps in that line - the email provider (yahoo, gmail, comcast, att.net etc.) and check out those spam settings.